# Quality of PCA in scikit-learn

Tags: python, math, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pca

I use PCA to transform my features in oder to reduce the number of dimensions. In order to tune the number of dimensions I need to know how well the original features are described by the PCA. How can that be determined in scikit-learn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can examine the `explained_variance_ratio_` attribute after fitting the [`PCA`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) object to see how much variance are captured by each PC.

Comment: And just take the .sum().sum() of it?